# Why Spherical tensors are more convenient to use in quantum mechanics than Cartesian tensors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, matrix-elements

I know that spherical tensors (more appropriately, tensors in spherical basis) are irreducible representations of the rotation group unlike the Cartesian tensors (more appropriately, tensors in cartesian basis). But why is it advantageous or useful to talk about spherical tensor operators (and their matrix elements) in quantum mechanics instead of Cartesian tensors? What advantage do we get?

Comment: You get it wrong. Spherical tensors are closer related to spherical harmonics, which are eigenfunctions of the $L^2$ and $L_z$ operators. Cartesian tensors are not. The advantage is that they commute with the Hamiltonian operator, and thus are good quantum numbers to think about. In a cubic lattice, Cartesian tensors may commute with the Hamiltonian operator, and then we might talk about their quantum numbers, which in this case is the momenta $\vec k$

Comment: Also, they don't always commute with the Hamiltonian. If the Hamiltonian does not possess spherical symmetries, then spherical tensors would be irrelevant.

Comment: They have many nice symmetries, and, for instance, in atomic optics they are very popular because electronic eigenstates in, let's say, hydrogen-like atoms have spherical harmonics as their angular part. As a results, if you want to find any matrix element, it is way easier to transform the operators in spherical tensor basis, as then it is super easy to compute. You can easily find things like selection rules (whether matrix element is zero or not, and for which quantum numbers it is zero).